# Android SlidingDrawer Position Handle Offscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

Is it possible to position a SlidingDrawer so that the handle is just below the bottom of the screen?

The functionality that I'm going for is that a user will press a button (not attached to the drawer) to slide the drawer up from below the screen. From there the user is able to use the handle to slide it back down.

Answer (score -2):

Use `View#setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `View#setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the handle.

Comment: When switching to visible, though, am I correct in saying that it would just show the handle in full height instantly instead of sliding the handle up from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Use an animation for that, handle.startAnimation().